# Why do I get ORA-27102 ON WINDOWS 64 BIT if I increase the memory to 2.5GB

Tags: oracle, memory

> BANNER
>
> ---
>
> Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit
>   Production PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production CORE    11.2.0.2.0
>   Production TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
>   NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production   Windows Server 2008 R2
>   Enterprise
>   6.00 GB RAM 64-bit operating system

Current memory settings

```
*.memory_max_target=1536M
*.memory_target=1024M
```

When I try to increase the memory_max_target to 2.5 GB I get the below error on startup

> ORA-27102: out of memory OSD-00022: additional error information
>   O/S-Error: (OS 1450) Insufficient system resources exist to complete
>   the requested
>
> SQL> startup
>   pfile='C:\oracle\app\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\database\INITorcl.ORA';

Could some one shed some light.

Answer (score 1):

How much real memory free does Windows task manager show, before you start up Oracle?  If less than 2.5 GB, that's the problem.  You can try increasing `memory_max_target` slowly from its current value, say in 256 MB increments, until it errors again, then I'd back it off by maybe 512 MB to give some headroom.